# DDD and Asynchronous Repositories

Tags: apache-flex, asynchronous, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

We're working on a rich client (written in Flex) that is connected to a Java backend, using both RMI and JMS. I was thinking about implementing the client in a DDD fashion so that it has Repositories for the CRUD operations on the domain objects.

The problem is however that all backend communication happens asynchronous and there is no way for me to force the client for waiting to continue untill it received a response. That means that, at a low level, I can call a method on a Remote Object and I get a AsyncToken as a return value. I can then listen to events on the asynctoken to see whether the call has passed or failed. This however breaks the main idea behind a repository, to hide the technical details from the client.

There might be 2 options I guess:

1. have the methods on the repository return the asynctoken, which seems like a messy solution to me
2. have the methods return an empty collection (for a findAll for instance) that will get filled when the response is received.

Both have pros and cons and I would like to get some input from you guys.

(taking this further, what would be good caching strategies? Dependind on the situation, I don't want the repository to call the server each time I request all entities from it. How would that affect the signature of the methods on the repository.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex and Flash Remoting is inherently asynchronous so fighting against that paradigm is going to give you a ton of trouble.  Our service delegates return AsyncToken from every method and we've never had a problem with it.

If you want to ensure that the application doesn't render a new view or perform some other logic until the result/fault comes back, you could do the following:

1. Attach an event listener for a custom event that will invoke your "post result/fault code"
2. Make the async call
3. Handle the result/fault
4. Dispatch the custom event to trigger your listener from #1

Bear in mind this going to lead to a lot of annoying boilterplate code every time you make an async call.  I would consider very carefully whether you really need a synchronous execution path.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend returning an AsyncToken as returning an empty collection just feels wrong.

In the case where you are returning data from a cache, return a CompletedAsyncToken (: AsyncToken) that automatically fires the COMPLETE event with the data whenever the COMPLETE event is subscribed to (and then removed the handler).

```
public class CompleteAsyncToken : AsyncToken
{
    public function CompleteAsyncToken(data : Object)
    {
        super(data);
    }

    public override addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false) : void
    {
        super.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

        if (type == Event.COMPLETE)
        {
            // Don't just execute listener as EventDispatcher is not that simple
            super.dispatchCompleteEvent();
            super.removeEventListener(type, listener);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just found this and it was useful to me so I thought I'd add to it. I imagine you would also want to override `addResponder(responder:IResponder)` and call `responder.result(some empty result object)` for any registered responder.

Answer (score 1):

One straegy would be to create a facade in front of the repository. Your client will make asychronous calls to the facade which in turn makes a synchronous call to your repository. This will allow your repository to continue working in a synchronous manner while the facade manages the asynchronous aspects of your call.