# Flex action wait for network response

Tags: apache-flex, synchronous

I have small Flex web based util with single button. On this button click a request is sent to server and the response must be read in the same call.
This is important not to wait for response with event handler (which is trivial).

Basically this is synchronous call.

I am ok with blocking ui and so on.

Is it possible to implement?

thank you

Comment: This question is asked ALL THE TIME, and always gets the same answer.  Please check the existing questions next time.  E.g.:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451090/as3-how-to-do-a-synchronous-load-of-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't any way to get result of the server call synchronously in Flash Player.